# Firebase logging garbage into console. Xcode - 8 (Swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, email, authentication, firebase

This below is the code I used. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()

    return true
}

....
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var Username: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var Password: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func CreateAccount(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: Username.text!, password: Password.text!, completion: {
        user, error in

        if error != nil{
            self.login()

        }
        else{
            print("User Created")
            self.login()
        }


    })
}

func login(){

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: Username.text!, password: Password.text!, completion: {
        user, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("Incorrect")

        }
        else{
            print("OK")

        }


    })


}


}
```

---

```
2016-09-18 23:25:22.601079 UserLogin[1613:81920] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventFiltered, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-18 23:25:22.602525 UserLogin[1613:81920] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEventIncoming, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-18 23:25:22.615489 UserLogin[1613:81918] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-18 23:25:22.632130 UserLogin[1613:81884] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: StatusBar, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-18 23:25:22.655849 UserLogin[1613:81884] subsystem: com.apple.SystemConfiguration, category: SCNetworkReachability, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-18 23:25:22.657839 UserLogin[1613:81884] subsystem: com.apple.network, category: , enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-18 23:25:22.658172 UserLogin[1613:81884] [] nw_resolver_create_dns_service_on_queue Starting host resolution app-measurement.com:0, flags 0x4000d000
2016-09-18 23:25:22.658 UserLogin[1613:81884] Configuring the default app.
2016-09-18 23:25:22.658981 UserLogin[1613:81922] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x3 ifindex=0 error=NoSuchRecord(-65554) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=::.0 ttl=60
2016-09-18 23:25:22.659724 UserLogin[1613:81922] [] nw_resolver_host_resolve_callback flags=0x2 ifindex=0 error=NoError(0) hostname=app-measurement.com. addr=216.58.221.142:0 ttl=247
2016-09-18 23:25:22.685692 UserLogin[1613:81884] subsystem: com.apple.securityd, category: OSStatus, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-18 23:25:22.686: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to remove checkin auth credentials from Keychain Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
2016-09-18 23:25:22.690: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Error failed to remove all tokens from keychain Error Domain=com.google.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
2016-09-18 23:25:22.691: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-09-18 23:25:22.692339 UserLogin[1613:81919] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 1 play.googleapis.com 443
2016-09-18 23:25:22.693333 UserLogin[1613:81919] [] tcp_connection_start 1 starting
2016-09-18 23:25:22.694450 UserLogin[1613:81919] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to play.googleapis.com:443
2016-09-18 23:25:22.695570 UserLogin[1613:81919] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7fde33d0d4e0
2016-09-18 23:25:22.695688 UserLogin[1613:81921] subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
2016-09-18 23:25:22.696348 UserLogin[1613:81919] [] __nw_connection_start_block_invoke 1 starting
2016-09-18 23:25:22.725488 UserLogin[1613:81919] [] nw_endpoint_handler_start [1 play.googleapis.com:443 initial path (null)]
2016-09-18 23:25:22.727001 UserLogin[1613:81918] [] tcp_connection_create_with_endpoint_and_parameters 2 device-provisioning.googleapis.com 443
2016-09-18 23:25:22.728774 UserLogin[1613:81919] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [1 play.googleapis.com:443 initial path (null)] reported event path:start
2016-09-18 23:25:22.729161 UserLogin[1613:81918] [] tcp_connection_start 2 starting
2016-09-18 23:25:22.729789 UserLogin[1613:81918] [] nw_connection_create creating connection to device-provisioning.googleapis.com:443
2016-09-18 23:25:22.731118 UserLogin[1613:81919] [] nw_endpoint_handler_path_change [1 play.googleapis.com:443 waiting path (satisfied)]
2016-09-18 23:25:22.731 UserLogin[1613:81884] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UserLogin.ViewController 0x7fde33c08950> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key UserName.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104cdb34b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010431f21e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104cdb299 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000103e2f2ff -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 291
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001052988c3 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010550cbe6 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c80590 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 256
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010550b56a -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1867
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010529eff5 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 386
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010529f917 -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010529fc4c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 201
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001052a04a0 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010516a045 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 71
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010516a796 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 293
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010517e0a9 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x00000001050f7259 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4818
    16  UIKit                               0x00000001050fd3b9 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1731
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001050fa539 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a1dd76b __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a1dd5e4 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010a1dd96d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c80311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c6559c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c64a86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104c64494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001050f8db6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    26  UIKit                               0x00000001050fef34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    27  UserLogin                           0x0000000102f97bbf main + 111
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010733a68d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2016-09-18 23:25:22.731704 UserLogin[1613:81918] [] tcp_connection_start starting tc_nwconn=0x7fde33e0a120
(lldb) c
```

Comment: Did your app run fine and gave you this garbage ? Or did it crashed

Comment: it start the simulator and shows blank white screen

Answer (score 21):

Just add **`OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`** to *`disable`* in your edit scheme **Environment Varibale**:-

Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> **Environment Varibales** ->

Click on the add button and add this key value pair to it:-

**`OS_ACTIVITY_MODE`** : *`disable`*

**PS:-** You also might wanna enable your keychain sharing capabities for your app. And check if your **`appName.entitlements`** has conformed to those changes.

**P.P.S:-** Also try running **`pod update`** , given Xcode8 GM just released , Firebase is most probably gonna fix these bugs in future updates.:- [Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/announcing-firebase-36-for-ios.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did OS_ACTIVITY_MODE : disable AND pod update. It is same that the simulator and shows blank white screen.

Comment: Make sure you have initialised a viewController as FirstViewController as initial view controller in storyboard

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps :

Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments -> **Environment Varibales** ->

Click on the add button and add this key value pair to it:-

**OS_ACTIVITY_MODE : disable**