# Firebase Xcode output in console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have recently installed the Firebase pods into my app as I want to be able to now check users and allow users to sign up.

However, this is what is in the Console:

> 2016-09-27 22:45:50.248 SampleApp[68417:]  Firebase Analytics v.3402000 started
>   2016-09-27 22:45:50.260785 SampleApp[68417:3132777] subsystem: com.apple.libsqlite3, category: logging, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
>   2016-09-27 22:45:50.278546 SampleApp[68417:3132701] subsystem: com.apple.BackBoardServices.fence, category: App, enable_level: 1, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0, enable_private_data: 0
>   2016-09-27 22:45:50.278 SampleApp[68417:]  To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ....)
>   2016-09-27 22:45:50.300 SampleApp[68417:]  Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
>   2016-09-27 22:45:50.360374 SampleApp[68417:3132797] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
>   2016-09-27 22:45:50.360821 SampleApp[68417:3132797] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
>   2016-09-27 22:45:50.361170 SampleApp[68417:3132797] [] nw_host_stats_add_src recv too small, received 24, expected 28
>   2016-09-27 22:45:50.361630 SampleApp[68417:3132797] [] nw_connection_endpoint_report [2.1 216.58.210.46:443 waiting path (satisfied)] reported event path:satisfied
>   [.....]nw_endpoint_handler_cancel [1.5 216.58.214.10:443 initial path  reported event path:start.
>
> There is more than 3000 chars in this output and SO will not let me post the full output.

I am very new to iOS development and especially Firebase.

The only code I have running in my viewDidLoad is:

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
        print("User Signed In")
    } else {
        print("Not logged in")
    }
```

I do not even know if this is the correct way to check if there is already a user logged in and I cannot begin to fathom what all this info is.

I have tried this: [Xcode 8 Console Garbage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37930506/xcode-8-console-garbage) but it did not resolve it.

Can someone tell me how to remove this or understand this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/39559602/6297658, http://stackoverflow.com/a/39560078/6297658

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a mix of 3 types of output

1. Xcode Console "garbage" -- Definitely give that solution you linked to another try. Sometimes you need to delete and re-install your app for it to take, but that will clean up nearly all the stuff that begins with `nw_` (And there's a lot of it!)
2. Normal Firebase output. This should be about 8-10 lines or so.
3. A bunch of scary-looking `FIRInstanceID` warnings. While you can generally ignore these warnings, they are kind of annoying / scary, so I would recommend fixing them by adding KeyChain sharing in your capabilities as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39550525/firinstanceid-warning-stop-will-reset-deviceid-from-memory-xcode-console-lo).

Comment: Thank you. Fixed it. Only about 8 lines now. Fear level down phew!