# Firebase currentUser returns nil after logging in

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I followed the instructions [here][1] to implement Google authentication through Firebase. Next I started working on the database. At the root of each database element is the the user, so I followed instructions [here][2] and found out the method `let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser` allows me to get the current users info.

To verify that was working correctly, I logged in and then added this in my code:

```
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    print("I added the below lines to easily find the print(user) statement int the log")
    print("HERE")
    print("HERE")
    print("HERE")
    print("HERE")
    print(user)
```

And unfortunately, it is printing `nil`.

I inspected my log output and didn't find anything suspicious, however I could be missing something so [here][3] is the entire log output.

Is it nil because I haven't added the user to the database, or something along those lines?

**UPDATE**

I now know that authentication is failing. I have confirmed this because after "Signing in", when I try to read/write to the database, I get a `permission denied` error -->  a result of not being authenticated.

Comment: See :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/39559979/6297658 for your console garbage

Comment: Thanks, cleaned that way up

Comment: In step 5 of the first set of Firebase docs you linked, is this being called, and succeeding? Seems like you don't have an authenticated user...

Comment: @BHendricks I have verified that authentication is successful through that function